# NestJS app with Prisma Client Error when running the app on AWS Lambda environment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nestjs, prisma, serverless-framework

I have a NestJS App that uses prisma.io as it's ORM and serverless for deploy and local testing.
Everything works just as planned when I run it locally, but when I deploy it to AWS Lambda and try to run, the result is the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '.prisma/client/index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/index.js\n- /var/task/src/database/prisma.js\n- /var/task/src/catalog/categories/categories.module.js\n- /var/task/src/app.module.js\n- /var/task/src/task-products.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '.prisma/client/index'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/index.js",
    "- /var/task/src/database/prisma.js",
    "- /var/task/src/catalog/categories/categories.module.js",
    "- /var/task/src/app.module.js",
    "- /var/task/src/task-products.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
    "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}
```

When that error occurs locally, I would just run the `npx prisma generate` command and it works, but it's not possible to do it in the AWS environment.

I've tried to include those files in the pattern section in the serverless.yaml file, but the error persists, also tried to copy the files using serverless-jetpack and it doesn't work either.

Here are my serverless.yaml file:

```
service: catalog-task

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-jetpack  

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  patterns:
    - 'node_modules/.prisma/client/**'
    - 'node_modules/@prisma/client/**'
  
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  deploymentMethod: direct
  timeout: 20
  region: us-east-2
  environment:
    VTEX_GRAPHQL_URL: ${env:VTEX_GRAPHQL_URL}
    MONGO_DB_URL: ${env:MONGO_DB_URL}
    VTEX_URL: ${env:VTEX_URL}
    DATABASE_URL: ${env:DATABASE_URL}

functions:
  categories-cron:
    handler: dist/src/lambda.handler
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 3 * * ? *)
  products-cron:
    handler: dist/src/task-products.handler
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 3 * * ? *)

# custom:
#   jetpack:
#     base: ./dist
#     include:
#       - package.json
#       - 'src/**'  # Incluindo arquivos fonte
#       - '!src/**/*.ts'  # Excluindo arquivos TypeScript, pois serão transpilados
#       - 'node_modules/.prisma/client/**'
#       - 'node_modules/@prisma/client/**'
#     exclude:
#       - node_modules/aws-sdk  # Exemplo de exclusão de um módulo desnecessário
```

my schema.prisma file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output = "../dist/.prisma/client"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

....
```